# How to merge Meshes with Textures?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have several meshes; each mesh has a different texture. Now I want to merge them all:

```
mergedGeo.merge( mesh.geometry, mesh.matrix);
```

This works fine.

But when I want to add the merged mesh to the scene, they information about the texture on each mesh is lost:

```
mergedGeo.computeFaceNormals();
group = new THREE.Mesh( mergedGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: parseInt("ffffff", 16) }));
group.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
group.updateMatrix();
scene.add( group );
```

I am using Revision 68.

Answer (score 1):

Each face has to have a proper material index.

Merge your geometries like so, incrementing `materialIndexOffset` each time, starting from 0:

```
mergedGeo.merge( mesh.geometry, mesh.matrix, materialIndexOffset );
...
```

Then construct a materials array:

```
var materials = [];
materials.push( material1 );
materials.push( material2 );
....
```

Then create your mesh:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( mergedGeo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
```

three.js r.68